# Continously running function, need to count actions

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm working with eye tracking and I'm trying to count the number of times a user is looking at a specific place on the screen. The problem is that while a user is looking in one of the specified areas, it will count until the user is looking away. Is there any way to set a timeout function or prevent the function from counting continously?

```
function onGazePoint(gazePoint) {

latestGazePoint = gazePoint;

overwolf.windows.getCurrentWindow(function(result) {
    if (result.status == "success") {
        if (isGazePointWithinWindow(result.window, gazePoint)) {
            document.getElementById("content").style.opacity = "1.0";
            /*var hotspot = ;*/
            var hotspotNum = document.getElementById('content').getAttribute('data-value');
            /*document.getElementById("hotspotnr").innerHTML = hotspotNum; */
            console.log(hotspotNum); 
            var hotspot = 0; 
            switch(hotspotNum) {
                case '1':            
                    document.getElementById("numberOfLooks").innerHTML = maplooks++; 
                    break;
                case '2':
                    document.getElementById("numberOfLooks").innerHTML = hotspotNum; 
                    break;
                case '3':
                    document.getElementById("numberOfLooks").innerHTML = hotspotNum; 
                    break;
                case '4':
                    document.getElementById("numberOfLooks").innerHTML = hotspotNum; 
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log(new Date().getTime(), hotspotNum); 
            }
        } 
        else {
            document.getElementById("content").style.opacity = "0.4";               
        };
    }
});
```

}

Comment: you could save the position and count only if a new position is given.

Comment: You'll have to show the code that actually triggers this handler multiple times. This just shows how you handle the gazing, not when it's triggered.

Comment: Clarifying to see if I understand your scenario: user looks at map, count goes to 1. Count stays at 1 while user stares at map. User looks away, then looks back, count goes to 2. User shakes their head rapidly 10 times, quickly looking away then going back, count goes up each time user's gaze passes the target. Count is now at 12. Then user stares at target again, counter goes to 13. Stays at 13 while user looks at it, then user looks away. Count is still at 13. Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Count goes up while the user is looking at the map. So it counts like twice a second until the user looks away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the counting problem you have to use a boolean variable as a semaphore. For example you set its value to false and the first time user looks in the area you set the value to true and count 1. Then until the flag value is true you stop counting and when user stop looking into this area you will reset the flag to false.

Comment: Ty so much! I have tried this before, but I just could not wrap my head around how I was supposed to set it to true/false, but with your explanation it worked like a charm!